# Diretório padrão de abertura do prompt no Node.js

Tags: node.js, prompt

Como faço para que o Node.js sempre abra num diretório o qual eu desejo? Sou novo nesta tecnologia. Queria saber como fazer para alterar o caminho padrão de abertura, pois atualmente ele abre sempre em `c:\users\meu_usuario`.

Segue imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nas propriedades do atalho, mudar "diretório base" adianta?

Comment: Ele inicia no canto em que determinei. Porém, ele não executa o node. Pois, quando eu digito algum comando ele não reconhece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este é um processo muito simples.
Quando estiver executando o prompt clique no ícone do prompt do node na barra de tarefas com o botão direito do mouse e em seguida faça o mesmo em Node.js command prompt e então em clique esquerdo em propriedades.

Na janela que abrir é só alterar o caminho do campo "iniciar em" e pronto. Sempre que abrir o prompt do node ele irá iniciar no diretório escolhido.